# recursive function calls segmentation fault in tree program in c

Tags: c, memory, tree

```c
// @brief recursively process directory dn and print its tree
// @param dn absolute or relative path string
// @param pstr prefix string printed in front of each entry
// @param stats pointer to statistics
// @param flags output control flags (F_*)
void processDir(const char *dn, const char *pstr, struct summary *stats, unsigned int flags)
{
  DIR *d = opendir(dn);

  // test the return value of opendir
  if (d == NULL) {
    printf(“cannot open directory”);
  }

  struct dirent *entry;
  //struct dirent *entries = malloc(sizeof(struct dirent)*MAX_DIR);
  struct dirent entries[MAX_DIR];
  
  int i = 0;

  while ((entry = getNext(d)) != NULL) {
    entries[i++] = *entry;
  }
  qsort(entries, i, sizeof(struct dirent), dirent_compare);
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    struct dirent this = entries[j];

    //char* out; char* tmp;
    //if (asprintf(&out, “%s”, pstr) == -1) {
    //  panic(“Out of memory”);
    //}
    //if (asprintf(&tmp, “%s%s”, out, this.d_name) == -1) {
    //  panic(“Out of memory.”);
    //}
    //out = tmp;
    //printf(“%s\n”, out);
    //free(out);
    
    printf(“%s%s\n”, pstr, this.d_name);

    processDir(this.d_name, pstr, stats, flags); // this recursive call causes segmentation fault
  }
  free(entries);
}
```

So the above is a function `processDir`, and the recursive function call at the end cauess segmentation fault.

executing the processDir function from the main outputs

```bash
 subdir1
Segmentation fault
```

If I get rid of the recursive call, then the outputs becomes

```bash
 subdir1
 subdir2
 subdir3
 one
 two
```

So calling processDir(’subdir1’, pstr, stats, flags) recursively triggers the error.

Additionally, the main function is as such.

```c
struct summary {
  unsigned int dirs;
  unsigned int files;
  unsigned int links;
  unsigned int fifos;
  unsigned int socks;

  unsigned long long size;
  unsigned long long blocks;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  struct summary tstat; struct summary dstat;
  for int (i = 0; i<ndir; i++) {
      memset(&dstat, 0, sizeof(dstat));
      processDir(directories[i], “  “, &dstat, flags);
  }
}
```

Any help or insight into what might be the cause for the error?

Comment: "*which means that the segmentation fault occurs right from the first recursive call*" -- it **suggests** that, I grant, but your program can segfault only by exercising undefined behavior, and if your program has undefined behavior then its behavior is *wholly* undefined.

Comment: `qsort(entries, i+1, ...` Why `+ 1`?? Sometimes getting used to 0 as the index of the first element of an array can be a struggle... Same with `j < i+1;`...

Comment: Is `MAX_DIR` a macro?  If so, then why are you allocating space dynamically for `entries`?  `struct dirent entries[MAX_DIR]` would be cleaner and clearer.  It's not like you're checking for allocation failure or anything, after all.

Comment: `out = tmp` leaks the original value of `out`.  Why are you even using two `asprintf()` calls in the first place?  It looks like you could use just one, instead: `asprintf(&out, “%s%s”, pstr, this.d_name)`.

Comment: Or actually, since the only thing you do with the final `out` before freeing it is to print its contents, you don't appear to need `asprintf()` at all.  Just `printf(“%s%s”, pstr, this.d_name);`.  Or did you maybe intend to pass it to the recursive call?

Comment: I don't see an obvious smoking gun, but the off-by-one errors that @Fe2O3 pointed out seem to be plausible candidates.    They are certainly *bona fide* errors that you need to fix, so there's no extra cost to you to go ahead and fix them, and see whether that resolves the issue.

Comment: Other possible issue: you do not test the return value of `opendir()`.  If it fails, then it will return a null pointer, which I imagine would cause an issue for `getNext()`.

Comment: There are several bugs in the posted code (some already mentioned in previous comments but also some that haven't been mentioned). But... the question lacks important information that are needed in order to post an answer. What is MAX_DIR? What is dirent_compare? What is getNext? We can guess (and probably do it correct) but you need to provide such information so we don't post answers based on guessing. I vote to close due to lack of information. If you edit the question and add relevant information, I'll remove my close vote.

Comment: In `if (d == NULL) {` you need to add a `return`. You don't want to go on if `opendir` returned NULL.

Comment: And `free(entries);` must be deleted (commented out) when you don't use `malloc`

Comment: `while ((entry = getNext(d)) != NULL) {` should be changed to `while (i < MAX_DIR && (entry = getNext(d)) != NULL) {`

Comment: BTW: I'm a bit surprised the output when you don't do recursive calls. It that all? Which OS?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the comments, they helped immensely. So obviously all the small and big errors pointed out in the comment sections were valid, such as the index errors and unnecessary use of asprintf().

Turns out what caused the segmentation error is the opendir() function call, because the path `dn` I’ve fed into it was wrong. So adding

```c
DIR *d = opendir(dn);
if (d == NULL) {
  return;    // this
}
```

eventually solved the error. Checking for errors is really vital after all.